# How to resolve the starting error in sonarqube?

Tags: sonarqube, azure-devops, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, sonarqube-scan

While giving `sudo update-rc.d -f sonar remove` I'm getting the below error

`insserv: warning: script 'K01sonarqube' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'sonarqube' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'sonar' missing LSB tags and overrides`

While starting sonarqube i'm getting

`● sonarqube.service - SonarQube service`

`Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/sonarqube.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Fri 2018-10-19 12:48:24 IST; 14s ago
  Process: 11420 ExecStop=/opt/sonarqube/sonarqube-6.7.5/bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 11372 ExecStart=/opt/sonarqube/sonarqube-6.7.5/bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 984 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)`

`Oct 19 12:48:24 master-VB systemd[1]: Started SonarQube service.
Oct 19 12:48:24 master-VB systemd[1]: sonarqube.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Oct 19 12:48:24 master-VB systemd[1]: Stopped SonarQube service.
Oct 19 12:48:24 master-VB systemd[1]: sonarqube.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Oct 19 12:48:24 master-VB systemd[1]: Failed to start SonarQube service.`